# How to convert date from an API response in a Django Template

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I have an API populating some data in one of my templates. The output of the date is `"2019-08-30T08:22:32.245-0700"` how can get the date to just read like `DD/MM/YY`

I have tried some templating `date:` type stuff, similar to what you would do with Jekyll but nothing works

this is how I am displaying it from the API response.

`<td class="text-center">{{ ticket.fields.updated }}</td>`

i tried something like:

`<td class="text-center">{{ ticket.fields.updated | date: "Y,D,M " }}</td>`

Trying:

```py
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    '''
        This view will hold infomation from Pendo / Salesforce and Jira
        using their APIs to display the infomation.
    '''
    model = Post
    template_name = 'clients/post_detail.html'

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        # pendo api
        pendo_result = api_calls.pendo_data()
        context['pendo_data'] = pendo_result

        # jira api
        jira_result = api_calls.jira_data()
        context['jira_data'] = jira_result['issues']

        return super().render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)

    @register.filter(expects_localtime=True, is_safe=False)
    def date(value, arg=None):

        jira_api = api_calls.jira_data()
        jira_date = jira_api['fields']['updated']

        if value in (None, ''):
            return ''

        if isinstance(value, str):
            api_date_format = jira_date
            value = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, api_date_format)

        try:
            return formats.date_format(value, arg)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                return format(value, arg)
            except AttributeError:
                return ''
```

Comment: What output are you getting when using the `|date:` template filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If retrieved from an external API, your data could be a string and not a Python `datetime.date` object.

In that case your options could be:

- custom template filter that converts string to date and formats it into a string with the desired format
- in your view convert strings to dates and format them into strings with the desired format

---

If you want a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), I would start by copying the source code from the [built-in `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date) and add a few lines to convert from string to datetime and then convert those datetimes back into strings with the new format.

Maybe like this, in a file called **your_app/templatetags/custom_tags.py**:

```
from django import template
from django.utils import formats
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(expects_localtime=True, is_safe=False)
def custom_date(value, arg=None):
    if value in (None, ''):
        return ''

    if isinstance(value, str):
        api_date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
        value = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, api_date_format)

    try:
        return formats.date_format(value, arg)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            return format(value, arg)
        except AttributeError:
            return ''
```

And then to be used in your template like this:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

<td class="text-center">
    {{ ticket.fields.updated|custom_date:"Y,D,M" }}
</td>
```

Comment: I do believe it's a string...would this need regex to convert into a better format? Can you explain the custom template filter? And how I would go about that, as i dont fancy regex lol

Comment: Something like my edit Ralf? I am not to sure what's meant to go here `api_date_format = '????'` So i took a guess above.

Comment: @mrpbennett I edited my answer; in case you wanna go with a custom template filter, this filter needs to be defined in a separate file (like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) say) and loaded into the template to be used. Normally your view should not need modifications if you go this route

Comment: this is awesome!! Thanks man...but i am getting an error `unconverted data remains: .745-0700` it seems `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` isnt covering it all i might be mistaken.

Comment: @mrpbennett look [in this table here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for how to represent the microsecond part